# slight difference between always and all the time

Tags: difference

I've heard from some people that "always" and "all the time" are not always interchangeable. I have written down a few sentences below.

(1a) Tom always writes novels at this table.

(1b) Tom writes novels at this table all the time.

(2a) They always go to math class with advanced calculators.

(2b) They go to math class with advanced calculators all the time.

(3a) I always enjoy working with you.

(3b) I enjoy working with you all the time.

In my examples, I think (1a)/(1b) and (2a)/(2b) mean the same meaning in their pairs. My non-native speaking friends think (3a) is OK but (3b) is wrong.

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 4):

In casual usage, they *may* be meant and used in the same way. (Although it would depend on the context.) However, there is certainly a difference in meaning.

Taking only the first pair (because the same thing applies to all of them):

> Tom always writes novels at this table.

This means that *when* Tom writes novels, he does his writing at this table instead of anywhere else. However, he may only write one month out of the year.

> Tom writes novels at this table all the time.

This means that Tom spends the majority of his time writing novels and that he writes those novels at this table. He's more likely to write eleven months out of the year (at the table).